# Debugging HTTP::Tiny

Tags: perl, https

I am using HTTP::Tiny to interact with rest api below an example :

```
my $req = $ua->get('https://myapi.com/user?xyz', {headers => 

     {token => 'xyzzz',
      data => '5343'.

     }});
```

i am using Data::Dumper to see the response header and body

```
print Dumper($req); -#i can see the response
```

is there an option to see also the HTTP request i am sending using HTTP::Tiny ,without the need of other tool like wireshark etc..
something like what mojo::useragent achieve with MOJO_CLIENT_DEBUG=1 any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see such a feature mentioned in the HTTP::Tiny documentation, nor do I see it facilitated in the source code for the module. However, you can use a module such as Test::MockModule to get a closer look at what is going on. Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTTP::Tiny;
use Test::MockModule;
use Data::Dumper;

my $t = HTTP::Tiny->new();

my $mock = Test::MockModule->new('HTTP::Tiny');

$mock->redefine('_request' => sub {
    warn "In _request: ", Dumper {self => $_[0], method => $_[1], url => $_[2], args => $_[3]};
    return $mock->original('_request')->(@_);
});

print "Response: ", Dumper $t->get('http://localhost:3000');
```

So in this snippet we are mocking `_request`, but the mock method we install in behalf of `_request` calls out to the original `_request` method, so our mocked method becomes a wrapper around the original method, and we can dump the underlying object and args passed into the method. I'm doing the dump prior to the request being made, but I could have done the initial dump, captured the return value of the real request, and then dump the object again afterward if I thought it might contain additional useful information. So long as we return the actual response, the calling code is none the wiser.

Here's an example of the output. The URL I'm hitting is just a default Mojolicious::Lite app.

```
In _request: $VAR1 = {
          'method' => 'GET',
          'self' => bless( {
                             'agent' => 'HTTP-Tiny/0.076',
                             'no_proxy' => [],
                             'max_redirect' => 5,
                             'keep_alive' => 1,
                             'verify_SSL' => 0,
                             'timeout' => 60
                           }, 'HTTP::Tiny' ),
          'args' => {},
          'url' => 'http://localhost:3000'
        };
Response: $VAR1 = {
          'headers' => {
                         'content-length' => '146',
                         'content-type' => 'text/html;charset=UTF-8',
                         'server' => 'Mojolicious (Perl)',
                         'date' => 'Sun, 26 May 2019 03:19:57 GMT'
                       },
          'protocol' => 'HTTP/1.1',
          'reason' => 'OK',
          'url' => 'http://localhost:3000',
          'success' => 1,
          'status' => '200',
          'content' => '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>Welcome</title></head>
  <body><h1>Welcome to the Mojolicious real-time web framework!</h1>
</body>
</html>
'
        };
```

Before I was able to know that `_request` was where I wanted to target my mock, I had to look at the source code for HTTP::Tiny. Fortunately the `::Tiny` part of the module means there's not a whole lot to look at. It's really a relatively simple module.

You may decide that for your own purposes it makes more sense to introduce your wrapper at some other point in HTTP::Tiny, but wrapping `_request` seems like a pretty good choice for most cases.